# Selection of data from one table and if it doesn't exist select from another in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables - tbl1 and tbl2

```
tbl1 has 2 columns -

user_id , updated_on

tbl2 has 2 columns -

account_name , inserted_on
```

I need to put a check , to search first in tbl2 for inserted_on date , if not found ,need to get the updated_on date from tbl1 and add 180 days to the date.

Flow :
tbl2 ->search for inserted_on date -> not found in tbl2 -> take the updated_on date from tbl1 and add 180 days to updated_on date

I tried this :

```
SELECT UPDATED_ON  FROM tbl1 t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT  INSERTED_ON FROM tbl2 t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.f_account_name
) ;
```

but this gives the updated_on date from t1 when there is no matching data in tbl2.

But I need the inserted_on date as well , like checking tbl2 selecting the inserted_on date if it exists else checking tbl1 selecting the updated_on date and add 180 days to it ..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like outer join to me:

```
select a.user_id, 
       nvl(b.inserted_on, a.updated_on + 180) as resulting_date
from tbl1 a left join tbl2 bon a.user_id = b.account_name
```

Comment: Addition of 180 will be done only on updated_on date if inserted_on date is not found in the tbl2 . tbl2 ->search for inserted_on date -> not found in tbl2 -> take the updated_on date from tbl1 and add 180 days to updated_on date

Comment: Aha; I thought 180 has to be added to *any* date you find. Just an objection: if "180" represents "6 months", consider using ADD_MONTHS instead, i.e. `nvl(b.inserted_on, add_months(a.updated_on, 6)) as resulting_date`